# How can i know if Kotlin created an equivalent class for existed java class or it used the original one?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm

I'm find myself, many times wondering if a method that I'm using belongs to a java source code or it been written also in Kotlin. Is there a way to know if the method that I am using is build in in Kotlin or indirectly use java method?

Comment: Ctrl + click the method in Android Studio or IntelliJ to jump to its source code.

Comment: @Tenfour04, so I made what you said on ArrayList and it took me to a weird file where there isn't any implementation for the methods and all the properties aren't initialized. Is Kotlin conceal theirs code?

Comment: Both Kotlin and Java's standard libraries are open source. Sounds like your project isn't configured to show sources. Does it not give you the option to do so at the top of this file?

Comment: @Tenfour04, maybe there is a problem with the way I do the things. First i'm writing mutableListOf, then ctrl+b, then I see the method: public inline fun <T> mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = ArrayList(), when click ctrl+b on *ArrayList()*, it takes me to a class with Kotlin Syntax but only declaration. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?Also on the class signature I see the word: *expect class...*

Comment: That’s because the Kotlin stdlib borrows the Java implementation of ArrayList. It’s a pass-through. Some classes from Java are mapped across to Kotlin by the compiler so they break the typical rules for some things, like renaming some methods.

Comment: @Tenfour04, ok. Thanks!!!